# QT Graphical Errors on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu

I am experiencing severe graphical issues in my QT application, to the point of it being unusable (see screenshot below.) I'm running the application on Ubuntu Linux through a VM (using VMWare Workstation) on my Macbook Pro. I've tried setting the QT_X11_NO_MITSHM and QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM flags to fix the issue, but it didn't do anything. Please help!

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Is it only in file open dialog or in every dialog?

Comment: Every dialog, as well as the drop-down menu at the top in the actual application.